# What am I doing wrong in this SQL query that tries to get IDs meeting a specific condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table with the fields: `asset_id`, `url`, and `url_source_id`. Some ids have several urls and several url sources.

When I run the query:

```
SELECT url_source_id, COUNT(DISTINCT asset_id)
FROM lookup_urls 
GROUP BY url_source_id
```

I get:

```
url_source_id   count
1   7202
2   9712
3   29
```

Which means that there must be a bunch of ids with `url_source_id = 2` that do not have a url with `url_source_id = 1`

However, **when I run the below I get an empty table. How can this be possible?**

```
SELECT *
FROM lookup_urls 
WHERE asset_id NOT IN (SELECT asset_id FROM lookup_urls WHERE url_source_id = 1)
```

Even more confusing, I do get results if I run:

```
SELECT *
FROM lookup_urls 
WHERE asset_id NOT IN (SELECT asset_id FROM lookup_urls WHERE url_source_id = 2)
```

Specifically, I get 6,780 unique asset_ids.

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: There is "utl_source_ID" in the first query but "utl_source" (without "ID") in the output. Can it be that you've mixed up columns having just similar names?

Comment: That was my mistake when "sanitizing" the column names in order to post them here.. I just corrected it in the question. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the `id` column is *not* unique on its own in the table?  This is a very non-standard practice and very much not recommended.  By almost universal convention, the name `id` is reserved for a unique non-null identifier column in a table (usually with an `identity` property, or a `sequence` or an `autonumber` field).

Comment: That's sad. I do not have any other ideas why could that happen. Could you also provide us with database and version please?

Comment: What DBMS is this?  Because certain aspects of this vary by the different DBMS products.  Specifically, null-handling wrt both `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` and `NOT IN(SELECT id ...)` depends on the DBMS and certain settings, and I very much suspect that as a cause here.

Comment: @RBarryYoung there is an `url_id` field which is unique, and `id` is actually called `asset_id`, I just changed it in my question in order to simplify things. But I'm gonna change it to the real name since it seems to be confusing things..

Comment: It's PostgreSQL

Comment: I have added the [postgresSql] tag as this question will probably require someone with that specific expertise to answer it (I do not have that myself).

Comment: It [worked](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/887b3d/2/0) for me. However, I did recieve an error/empty results when the 'url_source_id's where of a different data tpe than integer. Since you compare agains '1', the text representation of '"1"' won't be the same. Could that be your issue?

Comment: mm I've tried with  `url_source_id = '1'` but still I don't get anything. The column type is integer. It's very weird indeed. Thanks for the suggestion